# What should I use for Azure Mobile Service - TableController or API Controller?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-table-storage

I am working on a new application with Azure mobile app service and developing backend with .NET and choose Azure Tables as backend store. In all examples I found so far, are using TableController as base of any API controller and models must be derived from EntityData. This entity data does not contain Partition and Row Key, but we require these keys for Azure  Table storage. 
Other way to access Table storage is via Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage and models will be inherited from TableEntity.

Kindly suggest what is the appropriate way to develop backend service with azure mobile app.

Answer (score 2):

We can use Azure table Storage as a backing data provider for your TableControllers through the new Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Storage package. See detailed information from [Azure Mobile Apps September 2015 Update](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-mobile-apps-september-2015-update/). Detailed steps are shown in [this article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/mobile-services/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-store-data-table-storage.md). You need pay more attention to the following:
1) Different with Azure SQL Database, Azure Table Storage is a non-relational store.
2) The data type to derive from StorageData instead of EntityData, Id in StorageData must format as "<partitionID>,<rowValue>"

```html
    public class TodoItem : StorageData
    {
        public TodoItem(): base("partition", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        {

        }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public bool Complete { get; set; }

    }
```

3) Unlike a SQL Database, table storage as backend data doesn't return IQueryable.

Comment: StorageData looks like an option, but it has extra properties (CreatedAt, Deleted, Id etc....) which looks redundant as base table of StorageData is TableEntity and TableEntity already has some of these properties. I believe rather than to go for TableController, we should directly use CloudStorageAccount and TableOperation classes from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage namespace.

Comment: I think these properties(CreatedAT, Deleted) is very useful. Id is ignored. We only need some little code to use storage table as back-end, it is very simple. If you choose using TableOperation, I think you will have a lot of hard coding.